# How to convert dateTimeOffset from Hijri into Gregorian without changing current thread culture?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, datetimeoffset

When I get the value of a dateTimeOffset column from the database using EntityFrameworkCore I get the value of that column in **Hijri** when **CurrentCulture** & **CurrentUICulture** of the current thread is Arabic(ar-SA).

I know that if I changed the CurrentCulture of CurrentThread before returning that value I would get it in Gregorian calendar.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-UK");
```

But how can I return it as dateTimeOffset in Gregorian calendar without changing CurrentCulture of the CurrentThread?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion that the current culture affects how the EF Core creates the `DateTimeOffset` instance is incorrect.  `DateTimeOffset` and `DateTime` data types do not have a calendar unto themselves, and the thread's current culture does not affect how they are created (unless parsing from a string).

However, some instance methods, such as `ToString`, will use the current culture when they are called, unless otherwise specified.  Likely you are seeing string output created by `ToString` (whether explicitly or implicitly), and seeing the thread's current culture affecting the output there.

Therefore, simply pass a specific culture (often the `InvariantCulture`) to the `ToString` method, and you will see the output in the Gregorian calendar.

```
string myString = myDateTimeOffset.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first middleware of the pipeline I have added the following code:

```
 var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
 cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 var requestCulture = new RequestCulture(cultureInfo);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = requestCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = requestCulture;
```

Now the date is returned in the Gregorian calendar instead of Hijri.

Otherwise I think I should convert date implicitly without relying on CurrentCulture of the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

try this c#:

```
            CultureInfo arSA = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            arSA.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HijriCalendar();
            var toGegorian = DateTime.ParseExact("16/02/1444", "dd/MM/yyyy", arSA);

            Console.WriteLine(toGegorian);


           CultureInfo enSA = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
           DateTime dt = new DateTime(2022, 9, 12);
           string toHijri = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", enSA);
           Console.WriteLine(toHijri);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use one of the overloads for the ToString() function of the DateTimeOffset object that accepts an IFormatProvider parameter. This way you can present the object in the culture you specify, without changing the CurrentCulture.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-UK");
string representationUK = yourDateTimeOffset.ToString(culture);
```

You should be able to find more information on the Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_IFormatProvider_) page

Comment: I could do the following employee.CreatedOn.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) but I want to return dateTimeOffset